# Keep applications from focus stealing

Tags: macos

I guess it has been asked a couple of timed before in various settings, so I am going to make it more general.
There are some shitty applications ( like "Android File Transfer" for example ) which are stealing the focus / bring themselves to the front, whenever they are programmed to assume it's neccessary, even if a notification would do and especially since notifications can be muted.
That is extremely annoying, especially when you are in a very concentrated state.
Is there any way to turn this off system wide? ( I am still on High Sierra, but the question is also for other OS-iterations. )

Thanks a lot for all tips!

Comment: I’ve not seen this but if you can reference where this is asked or documented, at might help a good answer surface. My initial questions to triage this is if they pop up when minimized or left to run on a second screen in mission control? You might just need to assign these apps to a space or hush them to the dock.

Comment: In case of "Android File Transfer": Whenever something happens on the connected Android device, the application is bein brought to the front and displays a dialog with a confirmation button that closes the application. If the application was not running a deamon will start it. So moving it to another desktop or similar is not working.

Comment: If you're using Mojave, you may wish to [give this article a quick scan.](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-make-the-most-of-macos-mojaves-dark-mode/) And [this answer is worth reading if only because it may explain why this question has been asked so many times, and never answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541318/5395338)

Comment: Well, Mojave's dark mode does not help here, really. And for the second link: Well, yes, as someone who has been with MacOS sine Version 7  I have seen all the nice aspects of the Apple HIG gettimg diluted to the point of frustration.
Unfortunately there is no simple alternative to "Android File Transfer" apart from adb on command line ... Maybe I'll just write a wrapper for it.

Comment: I'm having the problem with any app either not preferring to open links in a window inside my currently active space, apps starting up not from command line when I want to continue working in the current app, and more bugs recently where they seem to randomly want to focus or with their in-app alerts.