# On iPhone, the Clock app steals focus after delivering a Notification

Tags: ios, notifications, clock, focus

I've got an iPhone SE, 3rd Gen, running iOS 16.6.1.

Let's say I'm using Google Maps to navigate somewhere while I'm driving, and one of my (many) alarms in the native Clock app goes off that I forgot to mute. The notification bar comes up. Now at this point, things are still fine. However, if I swipe away the notification, the Clock app steals the focus. This isn't just annoying, it could be a safety problem!

Now there are a number of questions I have about this:

1. Is there a way to swipe away the alarm notification so that the Clock app doesn't steal focus?
2. Is there a way to make one app, such as Google Maps, unable to lose the focus while, say, I'm using it for navigation?
3. Could I tweak some sort of Focus Mode (in the Focus App) such as Driving (which, incidentally, I do have set up!) to do what I want, here?

I notice there have been several other threads about stealing focus, such as [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428522/prevent-all-apps-in-macos-from-stealing-focus) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356265/keep-applications-from-focus-stealing). This seems a pretty basic thing: an operating system is supposed to manage physical resources for the user. The screen is a physical resource, so the OS should be managing it. And it should manage that resource intelligently, including allowing multiple apps to play well together. Currently, it doesn't appear that Apple is very serious about letting that happen. One app at a time works great. But when you have to have preempted resources that are subsequently released, iOS seems to fall flat on its face compared with Android.

I'd love to be proved wrong - perhaps I'm ignorant about some simple thing that would solve all these types of problems. Well, please let me know!